Certain Categories Missing Database Entries
I have noticed that certain categories in the database don't have entries.  Once they are saved manually, the entries appear, but there are much too many of them to save them all manually.
This is what the query "SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_text" shows before you save the category

and this is what the query shows after you save the category.

I need these database entries because I am planning on adding data to the categories and updating via the database makes it much faster.  Thus I need to resave all the categories so I can use the database to update them.  I tried the advice in this question Fastest way to load category and save programmatically in Magento 2, but I had the same "Invalid URL Key" error that the OP had.  I am wondering if anyone knows how to resolve the category save issue or knows another way to "refresh" the database so that these entries appear.

I see all values are empty. Do you have any data or all entries will be NULL? If NULL then you can write a simple MySQL query to insert directly in DB

Unfortunately, they are missing instead of NULL.  I thought about trying to write a program to insert the data, but with the way my data is, I think it would be safer to do manually.

If you have all the data then you can directly insert in database as well. Where is the data which you want to write?

Thank you for your help.  I figured out a way to do it this way by inserting the data rather than updating like you said.  This solves my problem, but it still would be nice for future readers to figure out what causes this behavior in the database.
